# Mongodb : How to position object to first place in sorted array

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have the following data:

```
answer: {
    questionid: Objectid(something),
    answers: [
      {
        user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
        isTrue: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
        },
        date: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

how can i query so i get the answer:true on top the results, then rest of the results sorted by date

EDIT:what i want is to check if any of the answers is true, and if so push it up, and all other answers that are not true will be sorted by date. think of it like stackoverflow question. if an answer is marked true, i want it all the way up, right below the question, if not true sort it by date.

Comment: Can you add a few complete sample documents as json to the question, and describe the expected output?

Comment: can show code which fetches data from mongodb?

Comment: just added some explanation let me know if you need anything else @SuleymanSah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation, unwind your answer array and do sort on answers isTrue is -1, because you want true first and then sort on date is -1 (descending order)

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
   {$unwind: "$answers"}, 
   {$sort: {"answers.isTrue": -1, "answers.date": -1}},
   {$group: {_id:"$_id", answers: {$push:"$answers"}}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort()` for sorting data in mongodb. In your case it will be like:

```
collection.find().sort({answers.answer: -1, answere.date: -1})
```

`-1` sorts your data in descending order.

**Edit**: sorting by date added as question changed.

Comment: just updated my code. what i want is to check if any of the answers is true, and if so push it up, and all other answers that are not true will be sorted by date

Comment: in that case you need to first push you data with answere:true and then rest you can sort your data by data in if condition after that push in same array

Comment: @SavanPadaliya read question correctly, he wanted to sort with answer and date.

Comment: @AshutoshSharma for your kind information i posted this answer before question was updated. After that you answered so did not updated my answer

Comment: @SavanPadaliya okay